# require vs Sass @import - live reload compiles all assets every time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

My colleague and I thought that it'd be a good idea to load CSS assets via Sass `@import` directive. One of the reasons was that I wanted to import variables and other shared assets once, at the top of the manifest file. But then a problem popped up.

It turned out that any little change done to any CSS source made live reload to compile all the CSS assets that were concatenated into `application.css` file. And it takes quite some time. Very bad.

So I'd like to make use of live reload and have some Sass partials loaded only once. Is it possible with standard, conventional `require`? How would you loaded these files?

Here is my CSS manifest file:
http://pastie.org/8333777

Comment: I think the reload of mini changes is not that bad. In development, it doesn't matter. In production, will you really push such mini css changes often?

Comment: Nope. Every mini change cause css assets to compile as if it had been done for the first time. So every time I do a change, it takes about 3-4 sec. That's the problem.

Comment: Did you mean that in development env?